# UNBLOCK ADDRESS

Tags: blockchain, tokens, address.transfer

I trust you are well.

I tried transferring my VRA to my address and I am facing this error
Fail with error 'ERC20MintablePausableBlocklistable: account is blocked'

Here below is my transaction ID/TX Hash.

0x3327ac81a0eb3ed614e810619c2b52379a3960d921be0694d34812d5d40e5145

Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Comment: Hello can you share more détails pléase toi trying To transfert token VRA ? What blockchain ? Share your code or more détails please

Answer (score 2):

You are on their blocklist.

I went through their source code. It seems your account is manually blocked by their admin. The only way to unblock yourself is to contact them directly.